# Build an approximately uniform grid from random sample (python)

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, scikit-learn

I want to build a grid from sampled data. I could use a machine learning - clustering algorithm, like k-means, but I want to restrict the centres to be roughly uniformly distributed.

I have come up with an approach using the scikit-learn nearest neighbours search: pick a point at random, delete all points within radius r then repeat. This works well, but wondering if anyone has a better (faster) way of doing this.

In response to comments I have tried two alternate methods, one turns out much slower the other is about the same...

Method 0 (my first attempt):

```
def get_centers0(X, r): 

    N = X.shape[0]
    D = X.shape[1]
    grid = np.zeros([0,D])
    nearest = near.NearestNeighbors(radius = r, algorithm = 'auto')

    while N > 0:
        nearest.fit(X)
        x = X[int(random()*N), :]
        _, del_x = nearest.radius_neighbors(x)
        X = np.delete(X, del_x[0], axis = 0)
        grid = np.vstack([grid, x])
        N = X.shape[0]

    return grid
```

Method 1 (using the precomputed graph):

```
def get_centers1(X, r): 

    N = X.shape[0]
    D = X.shape[1]
    grid = np.zeros([0,D])
    nearest = near.NearestNeighbors(radius = r, algorithm = 'auto')
    nearest.fit(X)
    graph = nearest.radius_neighbors_graph(X)

    #This method is very slow even before doing any 'pruning'
```

Method 2:

```
def get_centers2(X, r, k): 

    N = X.shape[0]
    D = X.shape[1]
    k = k
    grid = np.zeros([0,D])
    nearest = near.NearestNeighbors(radius = r, algorithm = 'auto')

    while N > 0:
        nearest.fit(X)
        x = X[np.random.randint(0,N,k), :]

        #min_dist = near.NearestNeighbors().fit(x).kneighbors(x, n_neighbors = 1, return_distance = True)
        min_dist = dist(x, k, 2, np.ones(k)) # where dist is a cython compiled function
        x = x[min_dist < 0.1,:]

        _, del_x = nearest.radius_neighbors(x)
        X = np.delete(X, del_x[0], axis = 0)
        grid = np.vstack([grid, x])
        N = X.shape[0]

    return grid
```

Running these as follows:

```
N = 50000
r = 0.1
x1 = np.random.rand(N)
x2 = np.random.rand(N)
X = np.vstack([x1, x2]).T

tic = time.time()
grid0 = get_centers0(X, r)
toc = time.time()
print 'Method 0: ' + str(toc - tic)

tic = time.time()
get_centers1(X, r)
toc = time.time()
print 'Method 1: ' + str(toc - tic)

tic = time.time()
grid2 = get_centers2(X, r)
toc = time.time()
print 'Method 1: ' + str(toc - tic)
```

Method 0 and 2 are about the same...

```
Method 0: 0.840130090714
Method 1: 2.23365592957
Method 2: 0.774812936783
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have come up with a very simple method which is much more efficient than my previous attempts.

This one simply loops over the data set and adds the current point to the list of grid points only if it is greater than r distance from all existing centers. This method is around 20 times faster than my previous attempts. Because there are no external libraries involved I can run this all in cython...

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
def get_centers_fast(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim = 2] x, double radius):

    cdef int N = x.shape[0]
    cdef int D = x.shape[1]
    cdef int m = 1
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim = 2] xc = np.zeros([10000, D])
    cdef double r = 0
    cdef double r_min = 10
    cdef int i, j, k

    for k in range(D):
        xc[0,k] = x[0,k]

    for i in range(1, N):
        r_min = 10
        for j in range(m):
            r = 0
            for k in range(D):
                r += (x[i, k] - xc[j, k])**2
            r = r**0.5
            if r < r_min:
                r_min = r
        if r_min > radius:
            m = m + 1
            for k in range(D):
                xc[m - 1,k] = x[i,k]

    nonzero = np.nonzero(xc[:,0])[0]
    xc = xc[nonzero,:]

    return xc
```

Running these methods as follows:

```
N = 40000
r = 0.1
x1 = np.random.normal(size = N)
x1 = (x1 - min(x1)) / (max(x1)-min(x1))
x2 = np.random.normal(size = N)
x2 = (x2 - min(x2)) / (max(x2)-min(x2))
X = np.vstack([x1, x2]).T

tic = time.time()
grid0 = gt.get_centers0(X, r)
toc = time.time()
print 'Method 0: ' + str(toc - tic)

tic = time.time()
grid2 = gt.get_centers2(X, r, 10)
toc = time.time()
print 'Method 2: ' + str(toc - tic)

tic = time.time()
grid3 = gt.get_centers_fast(X, r)
toc = time.time()
print 'Method 3: ' + str(toc - tic)
```

The new method is around 20 times faster. It could be made even faster, if I stopped looping early (e.g. if k successive iterations fail to produce a new center).

```
Method 0: 0.219595909119
Method 2: 0.191949129105
Method 3: 0.0127329826355
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure from the question exactly what you are trying to do.  You mention wanting to create an "approximate grid", or a "uniform distribution", while the code you provide selects a subset of points such that no pairwise distance is greater than `r`.

A couple possible suggestions:

- if what you want is an **approximate grid**, I would construct the grid you want to approximate, and then query for the nearest neighbor of each grid point.  Depending on your application, you might further trim these results to cut-out points whose distance from the grid point is larger than is useful for you.
- if what you want is an **approximately uniform distribution** drawn from among the points, I would do a kernel density estimate (`sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity`) at each point, and do a randomized sub-selection from the dataset weighted by the inverse of the local density at each point.
- if what you want is a **subset of points such that no pairwise distance is greater than** `r`, I would start by constructing a `radius_neighbors_graph` with radius `r`, which will, in one go, give you a list of all points which are too close together.  You can then use a pruning algorithm similar to the one you wrote above to remove points based on these sparse graph distances.

I hope that helps!

Comment: I am after your point 3. Wasn't aware of `radius_neighbors_graph` will give it a go and report back.

Comment: For the sample sizes that I have in mind the graph method seems to be much slower....

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could only re-fit the `nearest` object every k << N deletions to speedup the process. Most of the time the neighborhood structure should not change much.

Comment: Good point. I had an alternate version, where I only fit the `nearest` object at the beginning, then keep track of the points I had deleted so far. It was actually slower though, I think the problem was that when you refit you get a speed up as the remaining sample shrinks. You idea might get around this. I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are trying to reinvent one of the following:

- cluster features (see BIRCH)
- data bubbles (see "Data bubbles: Quality preserving performance boosting for hierarchical clustering")
- canopy pre-clustering

i.e. this concept has already been invented at least three times with small variations.

Technically, it is **not clustering**. K-means isn't really clustering either.

It is much more adequately described as **vector quantization**.

Comment: Thanks, I figured this would be the case. I don't suppose you could point me to a particular python library that does this stuff?